# How to count the combination of two column

Tags: sql, count, distinct, sql-server-2014

This is what current SQL that I got

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + RTRIM(CAST(ShipmentCargoContainersSummary.units AS VARCHAR(20))) + ' X ' + 
        CAST(RTRIM(ContainerType.description) AS VARCHAR(20)) [text()] FROM ...
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') fclVolume
        FROM Shipment INNER JOIN ....
```

the output

[image]

My question is how to fix this code so that I can count all these **as 11 rows** and get like this expected output: `8 X 40Hc, 3 X 20GP`.

Comment: @YogeshSharma thanks and done edit the post :)

Comment: @IntanNurShafienaz Add the sample data(how it's stored in your db tables)

Comment: This can be much more elegantly solved without your intermediate step of concatenating the `units` to the `description`.  How is your data actually stored in your database?

Comment: @YogeshSharma wait ya,, I still work on it.. thanks for your concern :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have data as below :

```
2X40'HC
1X40'HC
1X40'HC
1X20'GP
1X40'HC
1X40'HC
1X40'HC
1X20'GP
1X40'HC
1X40'HC
1X20'GP
```

Your, final result :

```
8 X 40Hc, 3 X 20GP
```

If all are correct, then you could try below `SQL Command` :

```
;WITH CTE
     AS (
     SELECT COUNT(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(DATA, 3, 2))) DATA1,
            SUBSTRING(DATA, 3, LEN(DATA)) DATA
     FROM <tablename>
     GROUP BY SUBSTRING(DATA, 3, LEN(DATA)))
     SELECT [DATA] = STUFF(
                          (
                              SELECT ','+REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), DATA1)+'X'+DATA, '''', '')
                              FROM CTE FOR XML PATH('')
                          ), 1, 1, '');
```

**Result :**

```
3X20GP,8X40HC
```

Hope, the above SQL Command will help you.

Comment: There is no need to parse out the quantities from the data as provided, as this is the result of a previous query that has the values available in the appropriate formats.  Please do not provide answers that completely skip over good practice due to a lack of investigation into the OP's actual situation and requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query (the WITH part is just to simulate original table with data).

In the inner query all spaces are removed and the position of X is found.

In the next query (starting from inside) what seems qty is extracted, together with the rest of the string (excluding X).

In the next query GROUP BY is made (I put two hypothesis, one with SUM and one with COUNT, but you can eliminate the one is not interesting for you).

The outer query format output as it seems you need.

```
WITH X AS (SELECT '2 X 40''HC' AS VOLUME
UNION ALL SELECT '1 X 40''HC'
UNION ALL SELECT '1 X 40''HC'
UNION ALL SELECT '12 X 20''GP'
UNION ALL SELECT '1 X 40''HC'
UNION ALL SELECT '1 X 40''HC'
UNION ALL SELECT '1 X 40''HC'
UNION ALL SELECT '1 X 20''GP'
UNION ALL SELECT '1 X 40''HC'
UNION ALL SELECT '1 X 40''HC'
UNION ALL SELECT '1 X 20''GP')

SELECT CAST (SUM_QTY AS VARCHAR(5))+' X ' +GRP  AS ONE_CASE
        ,CAST (NUM_QTY AS VARCHAR(5))+' X ' +GRP AS SECOND_CASE 
FROM (SELECT GRP, SUM(QTY) AS SUM_QTY, COUNT(*) AS NUM_QTY
    FROM (
        SELECT CAST(LEFT(VOLUME,pos1-1) AS int) AS QTY,
                SUBSTRING(VOLUME,pos1+1,LEN(VOLUME)) AS GRP
        FROM (SELECT CHARINDEX('X',REPLACE(VOLUME,' ' , '')) pos1, REPLACE(VOLUME,' ' , '') AS VOLUME FROM X) A
        ) B
    GROUP BY GRP
    ) C
```

Output:

```
ONE_CASE    SECOND_CASE
14 X 20'GP  3 X 20'GP
9 X 40'HC   8 X 40'HC
```

Comment: There is no need to parse out the quantities from the data as provided, as this is the result of a previous query that has the values available in the appropriate formats.  Please do not provide answers that completely skip over good practice due to a lack of investigation into the OP's actual situation and requirements.